# How to use Tochvision.Transforms

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I want to use `torchvision.transforms` but get the following error:

`TypeError: Input image tensor permitted channel values are [1, 3], but found 1080`

Using this code:

```
tensor = torch.tensor(image)
jitter = torchvision.transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=.5, hue=.3)
jitted_imgs = [jitter(tensor) for _ in range(4)]

cv.imwrite('jitted.png', jitted_imgs)
```

Array `image` has a shape of `(1080, 1920, 3)`, same as `tensor` which has a shape of `torch.Size([1080, 1920, 3])`.

How can I solve this problem and save my transformed image?

Answer (score 0):

Your channel axis should be first, not last.

Either use [`T.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html) and input your NumPy array into the transformation pipeline. To apply multiple transforms such as what we are trying to do here, you can compose them with the use of [`T.Compose`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Compose.html):

```
>>> transform = T.Compose([T.ToTensor(),
                           T.ColorJitter(brightness=.5, hue=.3)])

>>> jittered_img = transform(array)
```

Alternatively, you can permute the dimensions with [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) and apply `jitter`:

```
>>> jittered_img = jitter(tensor.permute(2,0,1))
```

Either way, you can then save your image by converting it back to PIL with [`T.ToPILImage`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage.html) and saving it to the filesystem.